# How can I add an icon to the launcher to show the desktop on 18.10?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I know I can use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to show the desktop - but how can I add an icon to do so as a favorite in the launcher?